# I don't see my track trace message in Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a simple console app that tracks trace. However, it's not logging the trace message in application insights from Azure web portal. What did I miss?

I've looked at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-console from docs.ms.com, and couldn't find an answer there.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "<KEY_HERE>";
        var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();

        // Get the object used to communicate with the FTP server
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpEndpoint);

        // FTP credentials
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpUserName, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpPassword);

        // FTP request method
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Successfully retrieved a list of FTP directories");
            telemetryClient.Flush();

            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Insights not logging custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551596/application-insights-not-logging-custom-events)

Comment: Messages are buffered internally and send once in a while to Application Insights. At the end of the application call the `Flush()` method to send the events.

Comment: @PeterBons Flush() will do it. Thanks for the help here.

Comment: @Jason Tang If you have solved your problem, please post your solution as  an answer to let others know.

Answer (score 0):

Need to put `TelemetryConfiguration` object in `TelemetryClient()`.
Please  make sure right key is assigned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).