# Setting custom username to Initializer Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I am looking to add a logged-in user's name to Application Insights to replace the cookie by default. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434924/setting-username-in-application-insights) that does something like this

```
public class RealUserIDTelemetryInitializer:ITelemetryInitializer
{
     public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
       {
       // Replace this with your custom logic
       if (DateTime.Now.Ticks % 2 > 0)
       {
            telemetry.Context.User.Id = "Ron Weasley";
       }
       else
       {
            telemetry.Context.User.Id = "Hermione Granger";
       }
     }
}
```

My question, is how do I pass data into this? I have a login method on my Api that returns some info, but calling into this Initializer is something I am confused on.

Answer (score 1):

We once had that same issue, although not for a user id but for an operation id. But the same principle can be applied here. We used a `Func<T>` that provides the data for the initializer (See full code of the initializer[here](https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring) and the usage [here](https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring/blob/master/src/ServiceFabric.Logging/LoggerFactoryBuilder.cs)).

```
public class RealUserIDTelemetryInitializer:ITelemetryInitializer
{
     private readonly Func<string> usernameProvider; 

     public RealUserIDTelemetryInitializer(Func<string> usernameProvider)
     {
         this.usernameProvider = usernameProvider;
     }
     public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
     {
           telemetry.Context.User.Id = usernameProvider.Invoke();
     }
}
```

Then add the initializer using code:

```
configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new RealUserIDTelemetryInitializer(() =>
            CallContext.LogicalGetData(UserId)?.ToString()));
```

As you can see in our case the data was provided using data on the current thread but in your case I suppose there is easier access to the username so you wil probably inject another Func.

Comment: Interesting, are you able to get Unique sessions doing this, or does it log everytime that CreateLoggerFactory() gets hit?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but basically every time AI wants to send out telemetry it will invoke the func first. So it is a one time setup in CreateLoggerFactory. (CreateLoggerFactory is called once upon starting the api). We create some [middleware](https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring/blob/master/src/ServiceFabric.Logging/Middleware/RequestTrackingMiddleware.cs#L33) that sets the data on the thread. The different threads make it a challenge since an initializer is not aware of any context.

Comment: We solved that challenge this way and it works like a charm, each requests gets its own unique id and we can correlate all AI events using this.

Comment: Well I will play around with this and see how it does. I will probably give you a check mark in a few days.

Comment: Have fun and if you get stuck let us know.